# Prim algorithm: show concerned edges with summation of edges weights

Tags: c++, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to modify this prim algorithm taken from here [prim algorithm](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/minimum-spanning-tree/tutorial/) to be able to show not only the summation of edges weights, but the edges too and it does not work properly.

**Remark : The code below is modified to show the maximum summation of edges weights.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
const int MAX = 1e4 + 5;
typedef pair<long long, int> PII;
bool marked[MAX];
vector <PII> adj[MAX];

long long prim(int x)
{
    priority_queue<PII, vector<PII>, less<PII> > Q; //changed greater by less
    int y;
    long long maxCost = 0;
    PII p;
    Q.push(make_pair(0, x));
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        // Select the edge with max weight
        p = Q.top();
        Q.pop();
        x = p.second;
        // Checking for cycle
        if(marked[x] == true)
            continue;
        maxCost += p.first;
        marked[x] = true;

        for(int i = 0;i < adj[x].size();++i)
        {
            y = adj[x][i].second;
            if(marked[y] == false){
                Q.push(adj[x][i]);
                cout << x << '-' << y << endl;
            }    
        }
    }
    return maxCost;
}

int main()
{
    int nodes, edges, x, y;
    long long weight, maxCost;
    cin >> nodes >> edges;
    for(int i = 0;i < edges;++i)
    {
        cin >> x >> y >> weight;
        adj[x].push_back(make_pair(weight, y));
        adj[y].push_back(make_pair(weight, x));
    }
    // Selecting 1 as the starting node
    maxCost = prim(1);
    cout << maxCost << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
4 5
1 2 7
1 4 6
4 2 9
4 3 8
2 3 6
```

**Output**

```
wrong output   expected ouput   

1-2            1-4
1-4            2-4
2-4            4-3
2-3            24
4-3
24
```

In this cas, I want to show only the concerned edges, but I do not know where exactly I need to show the x and y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print only the edges that make up the MST, you need to do this after popping an element from the queue. The inner `for` records candidates. These are not necessarily used. It seems as if you are not recording the complete edge in `Q` but only its weight and target vertex. If you want to print the edge, you also need to store the start vertex (or be able to recover it somehow).